# PHP process memory leak

Tags: linux, memory, php

I'm having a really strange problem when running a PHP script as a Daemon. First I want to say that I've been using those kind of scripts for several years now without any problem.
During the past weekend, I rebuilt one of our EC2 servers in AWS and I started to see some memory leaking from my daemon scripts..

I started monitoring one of them by adding a log on each cycle of my script.

```php
System_Daemon::info("After a cycle peak : ".number_format((memory_get_peak_usage()/1024/1024), 2)."MB and real : ".number_format((memory_get_usage()/1024/1024), 2)."MB");
```

Both numbers from this log are showing the exact same number for each script cycle

```
[Nov 21 10:24:14]     info: After a cycle peak : 5.31MB and real : 4.87MB
```

but when I look into the process on my system it's leaking memory. All the numbers regarding memory (VIRT,RES,SHR and %MEM) are going up until the process is shutdown by the system..

I really don't know where to start looking to fix this. The only difference I've seen before/after my server rebuild is that the PHP version has slightly changed from PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 to PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.7.

Can anyone help me understand what is going on?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to log using `memory_get_peak_usage(true)` - this will log allocated for whole process, not only memory used by your script. Maybe there is memory leak in PHP itself (or one of the extensions).

Comment: @mleko I just gave it a try, the numbers changed a little bit but they remain the same for each cycle.